# Expectations of the geometric mean of a random sample from a uniform distribution

Tags: distributions, self-study, mathematical-statistics, uniform-distribution

If I have a random sample of size n from a Uniform(0,1) and I define the geometric mean as G can anyone give me insight in to how I can find the expected value of G, E[G]? Once I can get my head around this I would like to extend it to the expected value of powers of G. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Exponentiated both sides and ended up with E[exp(G)] = E[exp(mu)]. This was from an online presentation I found. Then I guessed that the mean of a uniform(0,1) is 0.5 and subbed that in for mu. I am far from convinced with this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the same as finding 
$$E[(X_1 X_2 \cdots X_n)^{1/n}],$$ where $X_i$ are independent and uniformly distributed. Hence it is equal to
$$E[X_1^{1/n}]\cdots E[X_n^{1/n}] = E[X_1^{1/n}]^n = \left(\frac{1}{1+1/n}\right)^n.$$

Comment: Then I imagine I could replace the X with X^2 and so on to get the expected value for higher powers of G?

Comment: Yes, most certainly

Comment: I am afraid I don't understand the last step could you direct me to an appropriate reference?

Comment: That last step is known as the [Law of the Unconscious Statistician](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80874/expectation-of-reciprocal-of-a-variable/80878#80878), Jon. When $X$ has a Uniform$(0,1)$ distribution its distribution function is $dx$ (for $0\le x\le 1$). Therefore whenever $g$ is a measurable function of $X$ then $\mathbb{E}(g(x))=\int_0^1 g(x) dx$. Paulius has applied this to the function $g(X)=X^{1/n}$.  (Welcome to our site, Paulius!)