# Expected value of x to the power of a

Tags: expected-value

I would like to understand if $\mathbb{E}(x^a)$ is equal to $\mathbb{E}(x)^a$ if $0<a<1$. Generally I know that $\mathbb{E}(x^a) \neq \mathbb{E}(x)^a $ but under which conditions this could be not true?

Comment: See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/305713 for the basic ideas.

Answer (score 3):

It appears to be a homework assignment. So let me provide a hint.

Let $\phi(x) := x^a; ~a\in(0,1)$ be a real valued function.

Is it convex or concave? Compute $\phi^{\prime\prime}(x).$ Is it $>$ or $<0? $ For what values of $x? $ Then apply [Jensen's Inequality](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jensen%27s_inequality). What does it yield?

---

NB. Please note whuber's [comment](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/589707/expected-value-of-x-to-the-power-of-a#comment1090910_589716).

Comment: This is a good approach.  You are implicitly supposing, though, that $\Pr(x \lt 0) = 0.$  That's a fair presumption, but there are conceivable situations where $a$ is a rational number $p/q$ with odd denominator $q$ where we can make sense of $x^a$ for negative numbers, and then there will be nontrivial cases where equality can hold.

Comment: Hm @whuber. I cannot disagree here. That's a valid pointer.

Comment: On another note @whuber, might I propose you make it an answer in itself? It would be apt, imo.

Comment: I feel that my answer at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/305811/919 says enough.  This is just going over old ground with an inconsequential change, IMHO.