# Expectation of inverse of sum of iid random variables

Tags: probability, mathematical-statistics, random-variable, expected-value, indicator-function

**Description:**

There is a indicator function called $I_{i}^{k}$ as follows:
\begin{align*}
 \begin{split}
 I_{i}^{k}= \left\{
 \begin{array}{lr}
 1, \; {\rm if \; the  \; event \;  happened\; at\; time \;k\; for\; player\; i;}\\
 0, \; {\rm if  \; not.}
 \end{array}
 \right.
 \end{split}  
 \end{align*}
The event happened at least once, so $\mathbb{E}[I_{i}^{k}]=p_{i}>0$.  Besides,  the indicators
$I_{i}^{k}, \left\lbrace i=1,\dots N \right\rbrace $  are independent and
identically distributed (i.i.d.) with a fixed distribution across
time steps.

Now, we Let $\Gamma_{i}^{k}=\sum_{t=1}^{k}I_{i}^{t}$ and $\gamma_{i,k}={1}/{(\Gamma_{i}^{k})^{a}}$, $a\in (1/2, 1]$
for all $i$ and $k\geq 1$.

**Can we give the upper bound of the following?**

\begin{align*}
(a) \sum_{k=1}^{K}\mathbb{E}\left[ \gamma_{i,k}^{2}\right] \leq ?   \quad\quad  
(b) \sum_{k=1}^{K}\mathbb{E}\left[ \left| 
\gamma_{i,k}-\frac{1}{k^{a}p_{i}^{a}} \right| \right] 
\leq ?
\end{align*}
where $K$ is some constant.

**PS:** I think maybe it can be proved by `Taylor expansion`, but I don't know how to calculate it, maybe the following link is useful: [Expectation of inverse of sum of positive iid variables](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/399261/expectation-of-inverse-of-sum-of-positive-iid-variables/399289#399289)