# Bound on reciprocal moment - comment given in another question

Tags: probability

in this comment: [Expectation of reciprocal of a variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/80874/expectation-of-reciprocal-of-a-variable/80884#comment577999_80884)

I saw that BloXX said the following:

> Taylor approx. may only be useful if one has sequence of random variables $X_n-\mu=O_p(a_n)$ where $a_n\to 0$. Even then uniform integrability is needed additionally if interested in the expectation.

I am curious, is there a reference for what he's saying? Say I have some random variables $X_n$ with mean $\mu$ and variance $\sigma_n^2=a_n$ with $a_n\to 0$. Then are they saying that the Taylor expansion is valid?